# Take average between two columns for each row

Tags: r, average

I want to take the average of two columns by row.

More about the data: I had a bunch of participants come in for a study and I want to take their scores from two different columns, average them, and put them into a new column.

For example, I want this:

```
Participant #   Score A   Score B   Score C   Score D
1               30.0      32.0      48.2      39.2      
2               43.4      59.3      39.1      78.4
3               92.0      0.90      39.0      87.4
```

turned into this

```
    Participant #   Score A   Score B   Score C   Score D   Score A + B Average
    1               30.0      32.0      48.2      39.2      31.00
    2               43.4      59.3      39.1      78.4      51.35
    3               92.0      0.90      39.0      87.4      46.45
```

Thank you.

Comment: If there are no NA's, do `(df[2]+df[3])/2`  The second mean number seems to be incorrect

Comment: You can do `df$whatever <- rowMeans(df[2:3])`

Comment: Sorry I meant to add that there were different columns as well in the data frame. So I want to choose the columns.

Answer (score 4):

If the names of the columns for which a mean is desired are given by a character named `clnames` then try this:

```
clnames <- c("A","B")
dfrm$scrAM_means <- rowMeans ( dfrm[clnames] )
```

Answer (score 4):

Posting my comment as an answer.

```
df$scrAB_means <- (df[["Score A"]] + df[[["Score B"]])/2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the following:

```
 data$meanAB<-(data$scoreA+data$scoreB)/2
```

Or w/ dplyr

```
data<-data%>%
   group_by(participant)%>%
   mutate(meanAB=(scoreA+scoreB)/2)
```